# HK2 equivalent to Guice's static injection binding and ProviderBinding

Tags: java, guice, hk2

I have code like the following

```
public class ProcessorFactory {
  @Inject static Provider<Processor> processorProvider;
  ...
}

public class ProcessorProvider implements Provider<Processor> {
  ...
  @Override
  public Processor get() {
    ...
  }
}
```

and in Guice the binding is done as follows

```
bind(Processor.class).toProvider(ProcessorProvider.class).in(ServletScopes.REQUEST);

requestStaticInjection(ProcessorFactory.class);
```

However my project was set up by someone else using HK2. Can somebody help me with the equivalent binding in HK2? It seems there is only bind, bindAsContract, and bindFactory options...

Answer (score 0):

HK2 uses Factories where Guice uses Providers. If it's prohibitively difficult to reimplement your providers as factories, [HK2 devs recommend](https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2-160) creating a class that implements `Factory<T>` and accepts a Provider as a constructor arg.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. What about static injections? is there an equivalent for `requestStaticInjection`?

Comment: HK2 does not do static injection because of difficulties associated with the lifecycle of static injections (when can you be sure it has been injected?).  If you need static injections create a class with non-static injections (perhaps in @Immediate scope) and in the postConstruct of that thing set the statics you need set